# IS A relationship

Tags: mysql, entity-relationship

I have an entity in my schema called Ontological Domains. A domain can be either of the following: MF,BP,CC. I am thinking this is a case of an IS A relationship. However while translating this schema into relations, I realized that Ontological domain entity itself does not have any attribute to itself except Ontological domain id (Auto number). Was I wrong in assuming it was an IS A relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can still have an IS-A relationship. It's useful if you have another entity in your data model that references *any* ontological domain. In that case you would make a foreign key that references the parent `OntologicalDomain` table.

If you use MySQL, which does not have any direct support for table inheritance, you can use foreign keys and implement the [Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html) design pattern.

Using Class Table Inheritance is better than "polymorphic associations," where the foreign keys would reference any one of the MF, BP, CC tables.